# Confused with making an input into an empty array.

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm

Say I make an input : 
"Hello world" // hit a new line 
"Goodbye world" // second input

How could I scan through the two lines and input them separately in two different arrays. I believe I need to use getchar until it hits a '\n'. But how do I scan for the second input.

Thanks in advance. I am a beginner  in C so please It'd be helpful to do it without pointers as I haven't covered that topic.

Comment: use getchar until it hits a '\n' again.

Comment: Read about the `fgets()` function!

Comment: note : Input is not determined with the newline is not entered in the input stream to be buffered. E.g type Hello then 5 times BS-KEY then input Goodbye...  program receive `Goodbye...` , not receive Hello and BS-KEY in bufferd stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code out :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
  {
   int flx=0,fly=0;
   char a,b[10][100];
   while(1)
     {
      a=getchar();
      if(a==EOF) exit(0);
      else if(a=='\n')
        {
         flx++;
         fly=0;
         } 
      else
        {
         b[flx][fly++]=a;
          }
    }
  }
```

Here I use a two dimensional array to store the strings.I read the input character by character.First i create an infinite loop which continues reading characters.If the user enters the end of File character the input stops. If there is a newline character then flx variable is incremented and the next characters are stored in the next array position.You can refer to the strings stored with b[n] where n is the index.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you should probably look at is fgets.  At least on my system, the definition is as follows:

```
char *fgets(char * restrict str, int size, FILE * restrict stream);
```

So a very simple program to read input from the keyboard would run something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSTRINGSIZE 128

int main(void)
  {
    char array[2][MAXSTRINGSIZE];
    int i;
    void *result;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
        printf("Input String %d: ", i);
        result = fgets(&array[i][0], MAXSTRINGSIZE, stdin);
        if (result == NULL) exit(1);
      }
    printf("String 1: %s\nString 2: %s\n", &array[0][0], &array[1][0]);
    exit(0);
  }
```

That compiles and runs correctly on my system.  The only issue with fgets though is that is retains the newline character \n in the string.  So if you don't want that, you will need to remove it.  As for the *FILE parameter, stdin is a predefined *FILE structure that indicates standard input, or file descriptor 0.  There are also stdout for standard output (file descriptor 1) and a stderr for error messages and diagnostics (file descriptor 2).  The file descriptor numbers correspond to the ones used in a shell like so:

$$$-> cat somefile > someotherfile 2>&1

What that does is take outfile of file descriptor 2 and redirect it to 1 with 1 in turn being redirected to a file.  In addition, I am using the & operator because we are addressing parts of an array, and the functions in question (fgets, printf) require pointers.  As for the result, the man page for gets and fgets states the following:

> RETURN VALUES
>        Upon successful completion, fgets() and gets() return a pointer to the string.  If end-of-file occurs before any characters are read,
>   they return NULL and the buffer contents remain unchanged.  If an
>   error occurs, they return NULL and the buffer contents are
>   indeterminate.  The fgets() and gets() functions do not distinguish
>   between end-of-file and error, and callers must use feof(3) and
>   ferror(3) to determine which occurred.

So to make your code more robust, if you get a NULL result, you need to check for errors using ferror or end of file using feof and respond approperiately.  Furthermore, never *EVER* use gets.  The only way that you can use it securely is that you have to have the ability to see into the future, which clearly nobody can do so it cannot be used securely.  It will just open you up for a buffer overflow attack.